# ImageButton not firing Command binding in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding, viewmodel, imagebutton

I have an ImageButton that is not firing Command binding command using VMMV architecture. First all other bindings are working properly in the view.

Here is button:

```
<ImageButton Command="{Binding SelectedItemCommand}" Source="{Binding Logo}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="150" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"></ImageButton>
```

and in ViewModel:

```
public ICommand SelectedItemCommand => new Command(GetSelectedItem);
```

When I click the image nothing happens. I've even tried to bind to Pressed parameter but from everything I have read only the Command parameter should be used in a binding scenario. Putting a breakpoint on the function GetSelectedItem never gets reached.

What am I doing wrong here?

Sorry been away for a few days. So nothing was working on the suggestions even though they really should be clicking wouldn't fire command. Anyway I managed to get it to fire now using an eventhandler like so:

```
SelectedItemCommand = new Command<string>(param => OnItemSelected(param));

public void OnItemSelected(string img1_2)
{
  PressedEventHandler?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

The param captures the CommandParameter so I know which image to the question was clicked "img1" "img2" to do something specific. So my function now accepts a sender object and empty eventarg. I would like to instead pass img1_2 value but that doesn't appear to be possible as of now. What is cusrious is the sender object contains all the properties and values from the images (like an array of all my properties) but I cannot seem to get at them.
Attempted this:

```
string str = Item1Image.ToString(); // property in sender and viewmodel
```

But this returns a null value and not value listed in the sender object value?

Any additional thoughts?

TIA!
Rick...

Comment: you can only bind to public properties - you need a `get` to make it a property

Comment: Thanks Jason. So you are saying my public ICommand statement is wrong? I got this code from watching a video. I have also seen this in a "solved" issue that was almost exactly what I want to do. Anyway. So something like this:
public ICommand SelectedItemCommand { get; set;} ? How would I fire my function in this manner?

Comment: just assign it in the constructor like any property

Comment: Where did you put your ImageButton? The property could be fine.

Comment: Shaw if I follow your question the imagebutton is in my xaml page and my bindings are referenced in the xaml file back to my viewmodel where the code is writtten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ICommand SelectedItemCommand {get; private set;}

...

public YourViewModel(){
   ...
   SelectedItemCommand = new Command(GetSelectedItem);
   ...
}
...
```

Or

```
public ICommand SelectedItemCommand{
   get
   {
      return new Command(() => {
           //Do something
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks IInam but neither one is firing from the Command parameter when an item is clicked? The first option you suggested only fires when page is initially loaded.

Comment: change the code inside of your view model constructor to SelectedItemCommand = new Command(GetSelectedItem);

Comment: I was also able to figure out how to get the properties from the sender object. I needed to cast to my model again like QItems qitms = (QItems)sender; then use like so:
qitms.Item1Image...etc.

Comment: @Rick thumbs up